# How to get a desktop window image on a Unity3D-texture

Tags: unity-game-engine, hwnd, dwm

Using dwmapi.dll it is possible to "project" a real-time image of a desktop window onto another windows hwnd (DwmRegisterThumbnail) as used by the activity bar previews of running apps in Windows.

Now I want to project this image onto a texture in Unity3D instead. I haven't really tried yet but I'm guessing it actually could be impossible. Perhaps I can project it planarly directly onto a running  Unity3D-app but that's only close. I need it to be as a surface in full 3d.

Have anyone tried this? Please outline how it could be done if you think it is possible.